# Bootstrap Mixin columns not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mixins

Can someone please tell me why this isn't working? its driving me bananas.
I am using bootstrap.css (default unmodified)
css:

```
.wrapper {
.make-row();
}
.left {
.make-md-column(7);
}
.right {
.make-md-column(5);
}
```

html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="left">cake</div>
<div class="right">cake</div>
</div>
```

something I am missing?

Comment: Anyone please? I know it may seem like a silly question

Answer (score 0):

in SCSS syntax, you call mixins with `@include` like this:

```
.wrapper {
    @include make-row();
}
.left {
    @include make-md-column(7);
}
.right {
    @include make-md-column(5);
}
```